# Is there a limit on the size of chromecast custom receiver application?

Tags: chromecast, custom-receiver

I have chromecast custom receiver application that just show photo.
When I use photo size 2 mb it works, when photo 20 mb, custom receiver is crashes.
I use chromecast ultra.

Addition: Actually it depends on image resolution, not size. If resolution more then 7000 by width or heigh custom receiver crashes. Ratio doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media):

> Images have a display size limitation of 720p (1280x720). Images
>   should be optimized to 1280x720 or less to avoid scaling down on the
>   receiver device.

So you clearly have exceeded the limitation.